# What are some good powerful stotras that quickly destroy our bad karmas or sins

Tags: scripture, gods, stotra, yajur-veda, manuscripts

I believe that our past life sins can be destroyed or reduced through reciting stotras. I have read phalashruti of some stotras having such benefits. I want to know such stotras which are powerful enough to destroy our sins or bad karmas.

Comment: There are many such Stotras. From this page (https://www.hindupedia.com/en/Stotra) you can select few based on your Ishta Devta